# Entity Framework lazy loads all properties on all entities when they have the same many-to-many value. Is it a bug?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I noticed some unexpected behaviour when using 'partial proxies' with Entity Framework, ie not full change-tracking ones. I have a workaround but it looks like a bug to me.

My Currency class is many-to-many with other classes, such as BusinessEntity and a business Transaction. They all have a Currency property; in fact a Transaction has two, SourceCurrency and BookCurrency.

Given the code below, you would expect that SourceCurrency would be changed from GBP to USD, but it isn't:

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    // all currencies are currently set to GBP
    var transaction = ctx.Transactions.FindWithNullCheck(transactionId);
    var client = ctx.BusinessEntities.FindWithNullCheck(businessEntityId);
    var sourceCurrency = ctx.FindCurrencyByCode("USD");
    // var bookCurrency = client.Currency; 

    transaction.SourceCurrency = sourceCurrency;
    transaction.BookCurrency = client.Currency; // Bug here!

    ctx.SaveChanges();
};
```

What actually happens is that SourceCurrency is initially changed to the new USD currency but when we lazy load the client.Currency property, it is reset to its original value. It seems that the context is checking what other proxies share that value and regardless of the fact that they have been changed, it sets them.

I can prove this by stepping through the property setters in the debugger and all three properties are set at the same time as I touch client.Currency.

If I uncomment the statement:

```
var bookCurrency = client.Currency;
```

The problem goes away and the new setting is not overridden.

There are several issues related to the internal behaviour of EF proxies. It is difficult to say whether this is a bug or a quirk. I guess it is done by design but I would have assumed that changes already made to the property's value would be honoured by the code that synchronises all the lazy properties that share the same value.

My question is: do you think this is a bug that I should raise with the EF team?

Comment: What do these find methods do? Anything that can affect this behavior?

Comment: Just do a find and check the entity was found. They're not related to the problem:  var entity = collection.Find(id);
            Check.NotNull(entity, "entity");
            return entity;

Comment: I've taken a look at it, but with EF 6.1.1 I can't reproduce this. This used to be related with references (like `transaction.SourceCurrency`) not being loaded, so the change tracker didn't notice modification. But it seems that EF 6.1.1 has improved on that point.

Comment: I have had recent exchanges with the EF team about the null reference problems with partial proxies and as far as I know, it is still a live issue: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2074